# Firebase Delete User issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

If a user logs in anonymously and tries to access the MyPage tab, a pop up appears saying "You must create an account to access this page". When a user who has an account accesses this current page and touches deleteButton, they delete their information from the Firebase Database and I segue the user back to the initial Welcome Screen. The problem is the pop up always appears even when the user is already back at the Welcome Screen. How do I push to the Welcome screen after a user deletes their own account without showing the pop up.

```
class EditViewController: {

@IBAction func deleteButton(_ sender: Any) {
    deleteByID()
}
func deleteByID(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeVC") as! WelcomeVC

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    dataBaseRef.child("User").child((user?.uid)!).removeValue()
}


         func firebaseCallCompleted(data: AnyObject?, isSuccess: Bool, error: Error?, type: FirebaseCallType) {
    if(type == .UserInfo) {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        if(isSuccess) {
            if(data != nil) {
                let user = Users(snapshot: data as! DataSnapshot)
                if let username = user.name{
                    self.nameLabel.text = username

                        }
                        else {
                            print(error!.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            else  {
                hideUI()
                showCustomAlert()

                print("Anonymous user")
            }
        }
        else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if the user is logged in anonymously before showing the pop-up?

Something like this:

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
    if user.isAnonymous {
        // show pop-up
    }
}
```